# Changing size of non-client area in NCCALCSIZE when window is maximized causes flickering when maximizing with Aero Snap only

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to make a borderless window where the maximized window properly fits the work area of the screen when maximized. This has turned out to be more difficult than I could've ever imagined, and every solution I can find has some sort of downside or glitch that prevents it from being perfect. Some of the glitches are very minor and probably wouldn't be a big deal to most people, but it bothers me.

I know it's possible to do this somehow because I've used a few programs that clearly draw their own non-client area but have proper maximize behavior and appear to be without glitches. Steam and Twitch clients are two examples. However, I have no idea how much code or what sort of tricks they used to get their windows to have that behavior.

**Background Info:**

When maximizing a window, the window manager positions the window in such a way that the non-client area falls just outside of the visible work area so that the non-client area is not visible when the window is maximized. I remove the non-client area by returning 0 from WM_NCCALCSIZE because I want to be able to draw my own non-client area. The result is that the window manager is trying to account for a non-client area that doesn't exist and my maximized borderless window extends off the screen approximately 7 or 8 pixels in all directions.

**What I've tried to fix this:**

I've tried handling WM_MINMAXINFO, which doesn't work because the window manager ignores any dimensions passed unless they are smaller than the work area or monitor area. For example, if I subtract 1 from the ptMaxSize.x coordinate, the window fits almost perfectly except there's a 1 pixel transparent space where you can click whatever is behind the window. See [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150501-00/?p=44964) for more info.

**What almost works:**

I found [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5dbf69f5-12ed-4bfe-b754-e62f27caf612/i-need-to-set-the-ptmaxsize-member-of-minmaxinfo-to-the-screen-resolution-when-handling?forum=vcgeneral) which contains a solution that almost works perfectly, except that when maximizing the window with Aero Snap, there's a very brief flicker where you can see everything behind the window. This doesn't occur when maximizing the window by double clicking the title bar or using the maximize buttons, even when adjusting the size of the non-client area on maximize. [Here's a video](https://youtu.be/lpHXrkwWIEc) that demonstrates the issue.

**Video explanation:**

First, I maximize the window several times with Aero Snap without the adjustments being made to the non-client area to demonstrate that the maximize transition is flicker-free. Then I show that the window flickers after having adjusted the size of the non-client area on maximizing.

**My Question:**

Is there a way to prevent the flicker from happening when using this method to fit the maximized borderless window to the work area? Or is there a better way to go about making the maximized window fit the screen? Handling WM_MINMAXINFO seemed like the best hack-free approach, but because of the quirky way windows responds to dimensions that are greater than or equal to the work area, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Not sure if i clearly understand your question, but take a look at `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` API fucnction.

Comment: I probably should've mentioned in my post that I tried that already, but I've tried so many things that I guess I forgot. My thought process was that by extending the non-client area into the client area and painting over it instead of removing it completely would allow the window to fit the work area when maximized, since technically you aren't removing it. However, since the nonclient area becomes part of the client area when you do this, the problem persists.